# How to store templated objects of different type in container?

Tags: c++, templates

Assuming I have a `vector` (or `list` or whatever container might be more suitable here) that I would like to store multiple objects (or pointers) of a templated type in:

```
std::vector<MyClass<double>> v;
// std::vector<MyClass<double> *> v;
```

Unfortunately, I want to store different templated objects in this container (and I need to access them ideally at constant time).

My first intuition was to create some sort of `WrapperClass` around `MyClass` that would internally manage any `MyClass` as a member variable, but it's not clear to me how I could pass along the appropriate type through to `MyClass`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {}
};

// templating this of course works, but it doesn't solve my problem
template<typename T>
class WrapperClass
{
public:
    WrapperClass()
    {
        m_object = MyClass<T>();
    }

    ~WrapperClass() { }

private:
    MyClass<T> m_object;
};

int main()
{
    WrapperClass<bool> tmp = WrapperClass<bool>();

    std::vector<WrapperClass<bool> *> v;

    return 0;
}
```

So is there **(A)** a different container than `vector` that I could be using for this problem or **(B)** a way to select the type of `MyClass` in `WrapperClass` inside the constructor? I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
class WrapperClass2
{
public:
    WrapperClass2(unsigned int typeId)
    {
        switch (typeId)
        {
            case 0: m_object = new MyClass<bool>();
            case 1: m_object = new MyClass<int>();
            case 2: m_object = new MyClass<float>();
            default: m_object = new MyClass<double>();
        }
    }

    ~WrapperClass2()
    {
        delete m_object;
    }

private:
    MyClass * m_object;
};
```

Another idea may be to have some parent `AbstractType` that I would be using in the vector, but I'm not sure how that would help with the templated type problem.

Comment: Have all your templated classes inherit from a common base class. Store a pointer to the common base class in the vector.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that this may be the obvious and correct answer.

Comment: There are many possible solutions. What's reasonable depends on your `MyClass` template. It does appear to be an X/Y-question, though, asking about the imagined impractical solution Y to some original problem X.

Comment: Ok, I will extend my question - example a bit to make the intend more visible, but not sure I can follow your X/Y logic. I pretty clearly stated the problem and would be happy about any practical solution Z...

Comment: Note: the fact that the types are template instances is irrelevant. `MyType<double>` and `MyType<int>` are completely different and unrelated types, no different from how `MyOtherType` and `string` are different types.

Comment: The X/Y part is that you've already decided that you need a `vector` with different types stored in it. If you described the end goal instead, with the `vector` solution being one of the ways of achieving that goal, then someone might be able to suggest an alternate solution that avoids the `vector` altogether.

Comment: Actually, I say the opposite - I ask what I should be using: Quote: "or whatever container might be more suitable here"

Comment: Chris, I rolled back because it's uncool to change the question so drastically. No there are no answers yet, but you invalidated all of the commentary and made it look pretty silly because the commenters were recommending you try what you already had in your question.

Comment: I really don't understand the upvotes for the claim that I already decided on using a `vector`. If the answer is "don't use a vector", but use container XYZ, please let me know - that's what I was looking for and that's what I asked for if you would be so kind to read the the **first line** of the question.

Comment: I understand where the confusion is coming from now - I stupidly used `vector` in the question, which wasn't intended and I really hope I'm allowed to substitute this for `container`

Comment: It's not a simple issue of "don't use a vector, use container XYZ".  The issue is that we don't know why you need a container full of completely different types.  Since we don't know that, we can't suggest alternatives.

Comment: @user4581301 even though I understand your motivation - I don't fully agree with your decision that changing a question is not possible if it will invalidate some of the comments made

Comment: @MilesBudnek I tried to edit the question to include better info and example, but it was unfortunately reverted ...

Comment: how about `std::experimental::any` or `boost::any` or `boost::variant`?

Comment: @Chris, Looking at your edit doesn't make it any clearer why you need this.  Even if you could do this, how would you use `MyClass<int>` and `MyClass<string>` interchangeably?  You could use `boost::any` or similar as deW1 suggests, but at some point you have to know the type of the object you pull out of the list to do anything with it.

Comment: Chris, the problem is you changed the question from "How do I store the various template specialization is the same container" to "Now that I have an abstracted class, templates that extend it, and a container full of instances of said templates, how do I use it?" You are still allowed to edit the question to better explain the goal and hopefully reap the benefits of some different ideas on implementation. Just don't change the question. The answer may still be, "Smurf it. Use the abstracted class." And that may lead to you posting a new and different question, "How do I use it?"

Comment: this is not the place to have a discussion about edits. Take it to a chat room or to meta

Comment: @user4581301 I understand and I agree - thanks for looking at my question everyone

Comment: @deW1 I had a look at `boost:any` and will give it another try here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different instantiations of a class template are completely unrelated types, so you cannot have a container that directly stores them.

You have a few options:

1. Keep a collection of pointers to some base class that your class template inherits from:

```
class Base
{
    virtual ~Base {}
    virtual void someMethod() const = 0;
};
    
template <typename T>
class MyClass : public Base
{
    void someMethod() const
    {
        // stuff
    }
};
    
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> objs;
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique<MyClass<int>>());
    objs.push_back(std::make_unique<MyClass<std::string>>());

    for (auto& i : objs) {
        i->someMethod();
    }
}
```

This is a fairly simple approach, but it incurs a bit of runtime overhead with dynamic allocation and RTTI.  Note also that `someMethod` can't return `T`, since it's a method on a parent class that doesn't know what `T` is.

2. Use some sort of type-erased wrapper like `boost::any` (or the forthcoming `std::any` in C++17).

```
#include <any>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyClass {
 public:
  T someMethod() const {
    // stuff
    return {};
  }
};

void someFunctionThatTakesInt(int i) {}
void someFunctionThatTakesString(std::string s) {}

int main() {
  std::vector<std::any> objs;
  objs.push_back(MyClass<int>());
  objs.push_back(MyClass<std::string>());

  for (const auto& i : objs) {
    if (i.type() == typeid(MyClass<int>)) {
      auto& mc = std::any_cast<const MyClass<int>&>(i);
      someFunctionThatTakesInt(mc.someMethod());
    } else if (i.type() == typeid(MyClass<std::string>)) {
      auto& mc = std::any_cast<const MyClass<std::string>&>(i);
      someFunctionThatTakesString(mc.someMethod());
    }
  }
}
```

This approach means that you can have `someMethod` return `T`, but makes it much harder to handle retrieving objects from the `vector` because you have to figure out what type they are before you can do anything with them (you're essentially rolling your own RTTI).

3. Don't.

Rethink why you need this in the first place.  Maybe another approach could work better.  Maybe something with callbacks or visitors.  I don't know your objective here, so I can't really say what's appropriate.

Answer (score -3):

Can you do a base class and have all other classes inherit from the base class.

And you can make a list that holds a list of base class elements.
Now this is more of a pseudo example, but I hope this way would solve your problem.
Example:

```
class Base:
{
}

class whatever:Base
{
}

class whatever2:Base

int main()
{
 list<whatever> object1;
 list<whatever2> object2;

list<list<Base>> mainObj;
mainObj.push_back(object1);
mainObj.push_back(object2);

}
```

Now if the problem is to just have different datatypes than abstract datatypes in some container. Can't you have a Singly Link List, and have your Node generic.

Example:

```
template<typenameT>
struct Node
{
T data;
Node* next;
}

class LinkList
{
//Your code:
}
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly, what you need a container with different datatypes is, and I guess I wasn't able to get that info, since you weren't allowed to edit the question.

Comment: Your example slices `object1` and `object2` and creates `Base` objects in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by slices?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `object1` and `object2` are `list`s, so it just doesn't compile at all (`std::list<T>` is not convertible to `std::list<SomeBaseOfT>`).

Comment: I'm almost sure this does if written correctly and not in pseudo format, in C#  it absolutely works.  class Shape and class Triangle and class Square, both inherit from class Shape, and I make a list of triangle and list of squares I can then store both those into a list of Shape.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is C# or C++ in this case they both work out the same.

Comment: I will write this for you guys and show you guys that it works.

Comment: Waiting... This will never work in C++, not to mention this is not even a correct C++ syntax.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, but question the need for two lists and recommend brushing up on your C++ syntax.

Comment: @Polikdir okay after fiddling around with some code, it seems like I don't know the syntax in C++ as well as I thought, but I guess the concept in my head does work in another language and doesn't apply in C++, and I'll take your word on it that this is not possible in C++. However, I would like to know what is wrong with the 2nd approach of the linked list I had? Wouldn't the generic link list solve his problem?

Comment: @user4581301 I guess I can't exactly explain it perfectly, but yes my C++ does need some brushing up on. Also what is wrong with the 2nd approach I have with Link List for his solution?

Comment: You can have a linked list (or any template class) only of type `T`, which means it will be of only `int`s or only `Base`s etc.

Comment: Can you not have something like this if it is correct syntax?                                  template<typename T, typename Y, typename Z, etc,> One for each datatype or what you need to store and then inside the struct for node have T data; Y data; Z data;? As long as the Node is generic doesn't that mean the link list is generic?

Comment: `vector` is generic yet you can't do `std::vector<??> k = {5, "hi"};`, it will not work. If you still don't understand, try to search the web for templates in C++ or ask a new question here, in SO. This is clearly not something that should be going in the commnent section of an incorrect (and should be deleted) answer.